# What donuts should I pick?

Tags: yo-kai-watch-2-fleshy-souls

Right at the beginning of the game you are asked to choose between Soul Donuts and Spirit Donuts. Does this have any actual affect on the game? Does it matter what you pick?

Comment: Sprinkles. Always sprinkles.

Comment: @Ben Indeed!!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is version-locked, so you don't actually have a choice. If you're playing Fleshy Souls, you can only pick Soul Donuts. The mom will stop you otherwise.

[English source](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/786515-yo-kai-watch-2-bony-spirits/74365337) & [Japanese source](http://checkgame.blog.fc2.com/blog-entry-132.html)

Answer (score 1):

It's version locked for the base 2 games. Fleshy Souls, you always get soul donut. Bony Spirits, you always get spirit donut. Psychic Specters you just get to choose.

Comment: Hi Tristan, this doesn't add anything new that the previous answer already states

Comment: @TimmyJim It seems to add the information that you **do** get to choose in Psychic Spectres (which was only released outside Japan *after* the previous answer was posted & accepted), but doesn't answer whether this actually impacts anything.